# Ext Js: attaching user objects to widgets

Tags: javascript, extjs, ria

Is there a Ext Js API function or best practice or convention or attribute to attach user objects to Ext Js widgets?

Comment: If you feel the need to do this, odds are good that your app design is wrong.  What's the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you pass into the configuration object will be put as a property onto the Ext widget. There's no real convention as far as I'm aware.

If you want to get fancy you can have your user objects extend `Ext.Component` and define their [`ref` property](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-ref) so there's some standardisation.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the ref property. time to refactor and simplify things...